# Proof by induction: $n^{n+1} > (n + 1)^n$, $(1 + x)^n \ge 1 + nx$, other inequalities

Tags: induction, proof-writing

I'm struggling around my homework. I hope someone will point me the right direction for solving following examples:

- Prove that $n^{n+1} > (n + 1)^n$ for $n > 2$;
- Prove that $(1 + x)^n \ge 1 + nx$; $x \in\Bbb R$; $n \in\Bbb N$;
- Prove that $(2n)! < 2^{2n}(n!)^2$; $n \ge 1$;
- Prove that $2^n > n$:

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Show us what you did and where you are stuck.

Comment: So, do you not know what induction is?  What do you know about induction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first note that the inequality is equivalent to $n>(1+\frac1n)^n$

For the second note that $(1+nx)(1+x)=1+(n+1)x + n x^2\ge 1+(n+1)x$ and use this in an induction proof at least for the case $x\ge -1$. Think about it: Is the claim true at all if we allow very negative $x$? What about $x=-3$ and $n=5$?

For the third: Replace each odd factor $k$ in $(2n)!$ by $k+1$ and extract $2n$ factors of $2$ from the $2n$ (now) even factors.

The third is a very trivial induction.

Comment: Did you mean *fourth* in that last line?

Comment: While I realize the word has a (soft) mathematical meaning, it's kind of mean to call others' problems trivial.

Comment: It is not mean if it is indeed trivial, which it is.